# Why is Kendo sortable breaking my knockout select?

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am trying manage a list of items with a knockout viewmodel. The user needs to be able to change the order of the items, so I am using the kendo sortable widget to provide this functionality. I am also using a knockout select to allow the user to pick the type of each item. When I add the sortable functionality to the list the select stops working.

This fiddle demonstrates the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/pcbliss/sL12srnu/1/

```js
function item(i) {
  var self = this;

  self.Type = ko.observable(i.Type || 0);
  self.Name = ko.observable(i.Name || "New item");
}

function itemType(it) {
  var self = this;

  self.TypeId = ko.observable(it.TypeId || 0);
  self.TypeName = ko.observable(it.TypeName || "");
}

function ItemViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.itemTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
}

var model = new ItemViewModel();
model.items.push(new item({
  Type: 1,
  Name: "Item 1"
}));
model.items.push(new item({
  Type: 2,
  Name: "Item 2"
}));
model.items.push(new item({
  Type: 1,
  Name: "Item 3"
}));

model.itemTypes.push(new itemType({
  TypeId: 1,
  TypeName: "Type A"
}));
model.itemTypes.push(new itemType({
  TypeId: 2,
  TypeName: "Type B"
}));

ko.applyBindings(model);

$("#binding-sample-sortable").kendoSortable({
  handler: ".handler",
  ignore: "input",
  axis: "y",
  cursor: "move",
  placeholder: function(element) {
    return element.clone().css({
      "opacity": 0.3,
      "border": "1px dashed #000000"
    });
  },
  hint: function(e) {
    return $('<div class="modifier-hint modal-lg"><table class="table table-hover table-condensed edit-modifiers" style="margin-left: 0px;"><tbody><tr class="sortable-hint">' + e.html() + '</tr></tbody></table></div>');
  }
});
```

```css
  #binding-sample {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  #binding-sample-sortable {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .handler {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    background: url('../content/web/sortable/handle.png') no-repeat 50% 50% #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="binding-sample" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <div>
    <select class="form-control" name="TypeList" data-bind="options: $parent.itemTypes, value: Type,optionsText: 'TypeName', optionsValue: 'TypeId', optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
    <input data-bind="value: Type" />
    <input data-bind="value: Name" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="binding-sample-sortable" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <div> <span class="handler">&nbsp;</span>

    <select class="form-control" name="TypeList" data-bind="options: $parent.itemTypes, value: Type,optionsText: 'TypeName', optionsValue: 'TypeId', optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
    <input data-bind="value: Type" />
    <input data-bind="value: Name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

As a bonus, how can I get the edit fields to show their values during the drag operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. I had to add "select" to the ignore attribute of the sortable.

```js
function item(i) {
  var self = this;

  self.Type = ko.observable(i.Type || 0);
  self.Name = ko.observable(i.Name || "New item");
}

function itemType(it) {
  var self = this;

  self.TypeId = ko.observable(it.TypeId || 0);
  self.TypeName = ko.observable(it.TypeName || "");
}

function ItemViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.itemTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
}

var model = new ItemViewModel();
model.items.push(new item({
  Type: 1,
  Name: "Item 1"
}));
model.items.push(new item({
  Type: 2,
  Name: "Item 2"
}));
model.items.push(new item({
  Type: 1,
  Name: "Item 3"
}));

model.itemTypes.push(new itemType({
  TypeId: 1,
  TypeName: "Type A"
}));
model.itemTypes.push(new itemType({
  TypeId: 2,
  TypeName: "Type B"
}));

ko.applyBindings(model);

$("#binding-sample-sortable").kendoSortable({
  handler: ".handler",
  ignore: "select",
  axis: "y",
  cursor: "move",
  placeholder: function(element) {
    return element.clone().css({
      "opacity": 0.3,
      "border": "1px dashed #000000"
    });
  },
  hint: function(e) {
    return $('<div class="modifier-hint modal-lg"><table class="table table-hover table-condensed edit-modifiers" style="margin-left: 0px;"><tbody><tr class="sortable-hint">' + e.html() + '</tr></tbody></table></div>');
  }
});
```

```css
  #binding-sample {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  #binding-sample-sortable {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .handler {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    background: url('../content/web/sortable/handle.png') no-repeat 50% 50% #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="binding-sample" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <div>
    <select class="form-control" name="TypeList" data-bind="options: $parent.itemTypes, value: Type,optionsText: 'TypeName', optionsValue: 'TypeId', optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
    <input data-bind="value: Type" />
    <input data-bind="value: Name" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="binding-sample-sortable" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <div> <span class="handler">&nbsp;</span>

    <select class="form-control" name="TypeList" data-bind="options: $parent.itemTypes, value: Type,optionsText: 'TypeName', optionsValue: 'TypeId', optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
    <input data-bind="value: Type" />
    <input data-bind="value: Name" />
  </div>
</div>
```